# Why is text typing effect not working using GSAP?

Tags: javascript, gsap

## [GSAP TextPlugin](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/TextPlugin) not working

### Problem

- html

```html
<body>
    <section class="hero">
        <h1></h1>
    </section>
    ..... more html
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.4/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

[image: html-img]

- js

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(TextPlugin)
var master_tl = gsap.timeline();
master_tl.add(loading())
master_tl.add(heroAnimateIn())

// .... more js

function heroAnimateIn() {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    // tl.registerPlugin(TextPlugin);
    tl.to('h1', {duration: 2, text: "Hello World!", ease: "none"})
    return tl
}
```

- **The `h1` remains empty after the js runs.**

### What I want?

I want the tying effect like shown here [codepen source](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/kOgGMq)

### Note

- I am new to `gsap`.
- If any more information needed please tell in comments.